# lag daily data by 1 month in sas

Tags: sas, time-series, lag

I have a data set with daily data in SAS. I would like to convert this to monthly form by taking differences from the previous month's value by id. For example:

```
thedate, id, val
2012-01-01, 1, 10
2012-01-01, 2, 14
2012-01-02, 1, 11 
2012-01-02, 2, 12
...
2012-02-01, 1, 20
2012-02-01, 2, 15
```

I would like to output:

```
thedate, id, val
2012-02-01, 1, 10
2012-02-01, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  If you license SAS-ETS, there might be a better way to do it with PROC EXPAND.

```
*Setting up the dataset initially;
data have;
informat thedate YYMMDD10.;
input thedate id val;
datalines;
2012-01-01 1 10
2012-01-01 2 14
2012-01-02 1 11 
2012-01-02 2 12
2012-02-01 1 20
2012-02-01 2 15
;;;;
run;

*Sorting by ID and DATE so it is in the right order;
proc sort data=have;
by id thedate;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  retain lastval;  *This is retained from record to record, so the value carries down;
  by id thedate;
  if (first.id) or (last.id) or (day(thedate)=1); *The only records of interest - the first record, the last record, and any record that is the first of a month.;

  * To do END: if (first.id) or (last.id) or (thedate=intnx('MONTH',thedate,0,'E'));
  if first.id then call missing(lastval); *Each time ID changes, reset lastval to missing;
  if missing(lastval) then output; *This will be true for the first record of each ID only - put that record out without changes;
  else do;
    val = val-lastval; *set val to the new value (current value minus retained value);
    output;  *put the record out;
  end;
  lastval=sum(val,lastval); *this value is for the next record;
run;
```

Comment: i'm a bit new to sas. could you put in some comments so i can understand the code a bit better? thanks for your help

Comment: Done.  No problem.  Ask if you have anything else you're not sure about!

Comment: Joe, another question regarding your code: the statement `day(thedate)=1`: if I instead want to use end of money values, for example, is there a way to make this more general? ie use end of month days for example

Comment: What version of SAS are you using?

Comment: how do i check this? i'm using it on a cluster and submit batch jobs

Comment: SAS 9 by looking at the log file

Comment: Run a batch job consisting of "proc setinit; run;" That should get your version.  You could also look at the value of &SYSVER automatic macro variable.  You need the dot, since 9.3 and 9.2 and 9.1 have different functions in the time interval area.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25796/discussion-between-joe-and-alex)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a PROC SQL, and the intnx function to bring last months date forward a month...

```
proc sql ;
  create table lag as
  select b.thedate, b.id, (b.val - a.val) as val
  from mydata b
       left join
       mydata a on b.date = intnx('month',a.date,1,'s')
               and b.id   = a.id
  order by b.date, b.id ;
quit ;
```

This may need tweaking to handle scenarios where the previous month doesn't exist or months which have a different number of days to the previous month.